# Why does calling boost::split() give so many warnings?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I need a function for splitting strings on a dleimiter, and I'm using the boost library for other things, so I tried using boost::split. It works, but it gives me a bunch of warnings, and I'd like to know why.

The following is simplified code that produces the warnings in MSVC++ 10:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> split_vector;
    boost::split(split_vector, "string,to,split", boost::is_any_of(","));
    for(size_t i=0;i<split_vector.size();i++)  {
        std::cout << split_vector[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

There are about 100 lines of warnings, and I don't know how to make collapsible/scrollable stuff here, but they are all like:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2227): warning C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2212) : see declaration of 'std::_Copy_impl'
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_49_0\boost\algorithm\string\detail\classification.hpp(102) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::copy<const char*,char*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
with
[
    _OutIt=char *,
    _InIt=const char *
]
c:\program files\boost\boost_1_49_0\boost\algorithm\string\classification.hpp(206) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<CharT>::is_any_ofF<boost::iterator_range<IteratorT>>(const RangeT &)' being compiled
with
[
    CharT=char,
    IteratorT=const char *,
    RangeT=boost::iterator_range<const char *>
]
c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cas testing\tests\tests.cpp(10) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<CharT> boost::algorithm::is_any_of<const char[2]>(RangeT (&))' being compiled
with
[
    CharT=char,
    RangeT=const char [2]
]
```

and so on.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Boost: what's the cause of this warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301277/c-boost-whats-the-cause-of-this-warning)

Comment: It compiles without warning on ideone : http://ideone.com/LnNJA

Comment: @Nawaz It will most likely work just fine with VS as well. They just have some overly protective warnings. See the possible dupe I linked to. (Ps. didn't know ideone supported Boost. Nice)

Comment: This is just MS forcing their "standards" on everyone else. Disable the warning via the route the warning itself suggested and call it good.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd use `is_any_of` on a single character... that's what `std::equal_to` is for :)

Comment: @BillyONeal Can you point to an example for that? I can't get it to work in the expected way (simply replacing the is_any_of call with "std::equal_to(",")" doesn't work), and I'm unfamiliar with this functor stuff.

Comment: @CodingAloneTogether: You have to bind it: `std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<char>(), ',')`. (Yes, a bit less elegant, but more efficient and more close to what you want to do)

Comment: Ah, thanks, that works. If I end up using it a lot I'll probably define a macro or an inline function so I can just put, e.g., ',' or ".," as the third arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of the warning tells you everything, both why and how to avoid it, among other things this: To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.  So go to the project properties, and put _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS among predefined macros.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't actually doing anything wrong before disabling the warning. Disabled by just putting -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS on the commandline options for the project, but declaring _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS as a macro works too.